# hover img over background-image css

Tags: css, hover, background-image

I have an image set as a background like so

```
.about {
    height: 351px;
    background-image:url("../images/about.png");
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And I'm trying to user :hover

```
.about:hover {
    background-image:url("../images/hover.png");
}
```

to display another image over the top. I want the original picture to still be there as the hover image has transparency.

This way replaces the image, is there a way to not replace it but just hover over the original image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a mask, or an element inside your `.about` element (or positioned absolutely over it). The mask has the hover image as its background, but has `visibility:hidden`. Then, when the `.about` element is in hover state, it activates the mask. `.about:hover .about-mask {visibility: visible;}`. Pro tip: using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` allows the browser to load the image, even though its not visible, so you wont have any flickering.

http://jsfiddle.net/nDHbD/

Comment: Both pretty much the same answer, but extra kudos for the example but also love the extra bit of knowledge about loading the image in. Extra mile!

Answer (score 2):

You could place a div above the .about one, then have it display it's image on :hover, that way, both images would show. Even better, you could animate a transition on your new div so it goes smoothly.

Comment: This could work, but what if the hover effect would be used on more than one image? You'd have to call each hover div a different name otherwise they'd all show when you hover over one?

Comment: Not necessarily. The :hover effect could just be about positioning, (like : padding-top:350px), with the different images placed right in the div as <img> tags. 

That way, you could create a general class for your :hover divs and have them display different content.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SE6NY/ And that's the fiddle with different content on your hover div. :)